# On the dimension of moduli space of pointed curves with fixed Weierstrass semigroup

Tags: moduli-spaces, ag.algebraic-geometry

Does anyone know any information on the question of the dimension of moduli space of pointed curves with fixed Weierstrass semigroup? Some conjecture?

Comment: For those who (like me) didn't know the terminology:
"Given a curve X over a field k, an object classically studied is the Weierstrass semigroup of a k-rational point P of X. This semigroup consists of those nonnegative integers n such that there is a rational function on X with a pole of order n at P and no other poles."

Answer (score 5):

If the complement of the semigroup (the gaps) is $a_1,\ldots,a_g$, then the weight is $w=\sum (a_i-i)$. I think you expect codimension $w-1$ (for small $w>0$) for the space of curves of genus $g$ having the given semigroup. However, this cannot work for large $w$. Have a look at the papers of Steven Diaz.

Answer (score 2):

One good reference is "Recent progress in the study of Weierstrass points" by Eisenbud and Harris in Geometry Today, Birkhauser, 1985.